# Problems with JQuery Slider + Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a bit of trouble getting a Jquery event to work. When the slider moves it should update the referenced field with the value of the slider.
This doesn't currently work

Code can be found below and while it works at the jsfiddle link, it does not work at the second link, you can move the slider but the value of it does not display.

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2N4Y8/

Please ignore the double initiation of #slider.

I have tried to reproduce the code in jsfiddle as such:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<script>
 $(function () {
  $('#slider').slider({

      value: 50,
      min: 10,
      max: 100,
      step: 10
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#show-slider", function () {
      $('#slide').toggle("slow");
  });
  });
  $("#slider").slider({
  slide: function (event, ui) {
      $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
  },
  change: function (event, data) {
      alert(data.value)
  }
  });

  $("#slider-value").html($('#slider').slider('value'));</script>


<body>
<h5>You can alter the reading ease of the page using the slider below.<span id="show-    slider"> To toggle it click here.</span></h5>


<h5>The current Flesch reading ease score is at : <span id="slider-value"></span> </h5>

</div>
<div id="slide">
<br />
<div id="slider"></div>
<br />
<br />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The results of which can be found at :

http://shavid.webfactional.com/

As you can see, as per hosted here it doesn't appear to work, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get it. It's working on the fiddle. What's the question?

Comment: Check the bottom link, it doesn't work. http://shavid.webfactional.com/

Comment: The toggle click? Yea it works. 
What's your console output?

Comment: Sure you can move the toggle, but it's value does not display.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/2N4Y8/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website and it worked lol.

The code:

```
    $(function () {

      $('#slider').slider({
          value: 50,
          min: 10,
          max: 100,
          step: 10,
          slide: function (event, ui) {
              $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
          },
          change: function (event, data) {
              alert(data.value)
              $("#slider-value").html($('#slider').slider('value'));
          }
      });

      $("#show-slider").click(function()
                              {
                                  $('#slide').toggle("slow");
                              });
   });
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2N4Y8/12/). I just removed the one of the sliders initialization

Comment: Hi, I changed my website after you'd provided the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the fiddle and your site is that JSFiddle is wrapping the code inside of `$(window).load(function(){ /*code here*/ });`

Comment: His code already does that on the website. `$(function() { });`

Comment: This doesn't effect the webpage not outputting a value based upon the slider position.

Comment: @derek_duncan `$(function(){});` is not the same as `$(window).load(function(){});`. JSFiddle gives you the option on how to wrap your code and where to place it in the "Result" pane. Default being `onLoad`, which translates to `$(window).load(function(){});` in the `<head>` for jQuery library users.